# If I have a table with a column that contains Name like FIrstName.LastName

Tags: sql

How to get only the last name by using SQL Query?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: please provide the database you are using

Comment: What have you tried do far? We are not here to do your Job!

Comment: Considering the ambiguous nature of the question, you might want to check the answers on the following post which will likely lead you to a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006692/extract-characters-to-the-right-of-a-delimited-value-in-a-select-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using  an **oracle** rdbms, then you can use `substr` and `instr` functions to get the lastname from the `column`.

For ex.

```
Select substr(column_name, instr(column_name,".")) from the table_name
```

**Note**:-
 Assumed that dot (".") is present only once in the values.

For more reference you can refer [instr documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) and [substr documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)