# SQL Trim on a file name

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I am trying to trim a long file name and just want to get the last characters of that file name which is after the last forward slash (`\`) and I also want to eliminate the `.xlsx` at the end of the file name as well.

Original:

```
sasa\sasas\sasas\1234_IASS.xlsx
```

Expected Output:

```
1234_IASS
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff just wanted to get the output after the last \ and take out the .xlsx part from the end

Comment: Do all your filenames end with .xlsx? Do any of the files have a different extension, do any of the extensions have three characters instead of four?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller yes all file names end with the same extension and with the same number of characters

Comment: Are these file paths stored in a table?

Comment: @gbeaven yes they are but the file names are different and the file path remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments state that both your file path and file extension are constant. If the number of characters in your file is also constant the simplest solution is to use `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 18, 9)
FROM YourTable
```

If the number of characters is changing, a more robust solution is to use `RIGHT` to extract the file name and `REPLACE` to remove the file extension.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(YourColumn, LEN(YourColumn) - 17), '.xlsx', '')
FROM YourTable
```

If you need a more dynamic solution, you can first extract the filename as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19006764/3194005).

```
SELECT RIGHT(YourColumn, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(YourColumn)) - 1)
FROM YourTable
```

You can then combine this with `REPLACE` as before to remove the extension.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(YourColumn, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(YourColumn)) - 1), '.xlsx', '')
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it will work as said in the comment the file extension are fixed.

```
SELECT 
Replace(
    RIGHT('\' + RTRIM('sasa\sasas\sasas\1234_IASS.xlsx'), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\' + RTRIM('sasa\sasas\sasas\1234_IASS.xlsx'))) - 1)
          ,'.xlsx', '') 
as FileName
```

You can find the live [example here](https://rextester.com/VMJDS56051).

Comment: Hi, I just used this file name as an example but when extracting the data from the table all file names are different. So how will I use this ?

Comment: by doing this way it replaces all the file names with the name 1234_IASS

Comment: @Minhal the same will work as it is also working for the example: sa sa\s asas\sasa s\1234_IASS.xlsx

Comment: @Minhal pass the field as the filepath, don't leave it hardcoded like this answer suggests.

Comment: @gbeaven Yes for calling on a table the column name of file path needed to supply.

Comment: @Minhal Thanks for let me know and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your post's title is misleading, `TRIM` is performed in `sql-server` to remove whitespace either by `RTRIM` or `LTRIM` or a combination of the two, what you are trying to do is get a substring out of your example string, I am providing a solution which uses a combination of `REVERSE`, `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`, this answer is good for if you ever need to do this for different file extensions:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(255) = 'sasa\sasas\sasas\1234_IASS.xlsx';
DECLARE @lastOccurance INT = CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@test)); --Last occurence of the slash character to denote the end of the directory name or what not
DECLARE @lastPeriod INT = CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@test)); --This is the last occurence of the period, denoting the file extension
SET @lastOccurance = LEN(@test) + 1 - @lastOccurance;
SET @lastPeriod = LEN(@test) + 1 - @lastPeriod;
SELECT SUBSTRING(@test, @lastOccurance + 1, @lastPeriod - (@lastOccurance + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You say your directory is the same and the extension is always the same? Replace `[path]` with your table column name:

```
select replace(replace([path],'sasa\sasas\sasas\',''),'.xlsx','')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @x varchar(100) = 'sasa\sasas\sasas\1234_IASS.xlsx'

declare @filename varchar(max) = reverse(substring(reverse(@x), 1, charindex('\', reverse(@x))-1 ))
select substring(@filename, 1, charindex('.', @filename)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove extensions from filename then you can try this:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FileName = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FileName), 
                       CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(FileName)) + 1, 999))
```